# How to require more than one cookie htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security, cookies

I would like to know how to require more than one cookie E.G.
to access `example.com/protected` you need both
`cookie1 and cookie 2`

Here is my current HTACCESS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cookietest/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !AuthCookie=OpenSesame [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com.com/wp-login.php [L]
```

How do I require BOTH cookies?

Comment: [`rewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) is implicitly `AND` unless `OR` is specified.

Comment: So the below answer is not valid?

Comment: My mistake. Yes, the answer below looks great. I didn't notice that both you and JonLin are negating your conditions.

Comment: Negating Conditions? the [NC]?

Comment: No, I mean the `!` negation. [`[NC]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) is for case insensitivity ("no case").

Comment: OOOOOhhhhhh..... ok that is enlightening! Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `OR` flag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cookietest/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !AuthCookie=OpenSesame [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com.com/wp-login.php [L]
```

If either AuthCookie *OR* wordpress_logged_in is missing, then redirect to the wp-login.php. If BOTH cookies exist, then BOTH conditions won't be met and thus you won't get redirected

Comment: and this will require BOTH cookies?

Comment: @ElliotLabs yes, if either `AuthCookie` **OR** `wordpress_logged_in` is missing, then redirect to the wp-login.php. If **BOTH** cookies exist, then **BOTH** conditions won't be met and thus you won't get redirected.